# Integration with substitution results in 1/du

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider following integral:

$$F(x) = \int \frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{ln(x)}dx$$

which we can substitute with $u = u(x) = ln(x)$:

$$\int \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{u}dx$$

then we can find $dx$:

$$u'(x) = \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \iff dx = \frac{x}{du}$$

so we can insert this into our substituted integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{u} \frac{x}{du}$$

this allows us to get rid of $\frac{1}{x}$:

$$\int \frac{1}{u} \frac{1}{du}$$

**but it leaves us with $\frac{1}{du}$ which is no valid integral expression.**

I also tried out to set $u = x \cdot ln(x)$ which yields in $\frac{ln(x \cdot ln(x))}{ln(x)+1} + C$. Consulting [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28xln%28x%29%29) shows that this is not a valid answer also they substituted $u = ln(x)$ as I tried.

Comment: From $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$, you don't get $dx=\frac{x}{du}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your this step is wrong:
$$dx = \frac{x}{du}\tag{wrong}$$
Instead it should be:
$$dx=xdu\tag{right}$$
$$f(x)=\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}=\int\frac{d(\ln x)}{\ln x}=\ln(\ln x)+c$$